# How to query on mongoDB collection to find user in radius_spherical using mongoid_geospatial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, geospatial, mongodb-query

I am using Mongoid_geospatial gem with Rails 4. My query is

```
@data = Place.near(location: coords.radius(100)).
 @temp << @data.map { |d| d.location }
```

Where `coords = #<Mongoid::Geospatial::Point:0x00000002fdcc88 @x=-6.229019, @y=53.352277>`

It throws and error " 
The operation: #{"$near"=>[[-6.229019, 53.352277], 100]}} @fields=nil> failed with error 17287: "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue $geometry is required for geo near query" See https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/docs/errors.md for details about this error"

my models are

```
class Place
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Geospatial

  field :location, type: Point

  belongs_to :user

  spatial_index :location

end
```

can someone explain what the error is about ? where am i going wrong, what should i do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it resolved

```
#Querying MongoDB to search users near coordinates: @searchResult will be an array of BSON docs.
      @searchResult = Place.geo_near(coordinates).spherical.max_distance(distance)

      #extracting coordinates from Result to compare it with @present Users as well as empty set
      @resultCoords = @searchResult.map { |e| e.location.coordinates  }
```